# update records in APEX from a list of record

Tags: apex

I have a component where, when the user click on Save it fires an apex class that is supposed to update the records

The way it work is that onClick on save it creates a list of dict with the relevant data that need to be updated for example [{id:1234, name:'recordName'}, {id:1234566, name:'record2'}]

I tried to set up my Apex class but it seems that there is something I do not get in Apex
JavaScript:

```
handleSave() {
        this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Saving...'
        let toSaveList = [];
        //console.log(toSaveList)
        
        this.myList.forEach((element, index) => {
            if (element.changed === true){
                toSaveList.push(element)
            }
        console.log(toSaveList)
        saveOutreachProperty({records : toSaveList})
        .then(() => {
            this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Saved';
            
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title : 'Success',
                    message : `Records saved succesfully!`,
                    variant : 'success',
                }),
            )
            this.isEdited = false;
            this.error = undefined;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
            console.log("Error in Save call back:", this.error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Save';
            }, 3000);
        });


        
        });
```

ApexClass:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static void saveOutreachProperty(List<Lead> records){
        if(records.size()>0 && records != null){     
            for(integer i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
                Lead PropToMigrate = [SELECT Id, Name, Status, LeadSource, Number_of_Keys__c, Neighbourhood__c 
                              FROM lead 
                              WHERE Id = records[i].id
                              LIMIT 1]; 
                PropToMigrate.Name = records[i].Name;
                update PropToMigrate;
            }      
        }
    }
```

edited ApexClass:

```
@AuraEnabled()
    public static void saveOutreachProperty(List<Lead> records) {
        if(records != null) {
            update records;
    }
```

Could you please help me to have my records updated and eplxplain me what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute a DML, you must remove `cacheable=true`. [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_result_caching):

> To set cacheable=true, a method must only get data, **it can’t mutate (change) data**.

Beware: the if condition is wrong. In your code, if records is null, you'll get a NullPointerException because you first check if it's empty calling a method on `records`, then you check if it's null. The null check should always be the first one.
I.E. `if (records != null && !record.isEmpty())`

Finally the method isn't bulkified. You have both a SOQL and a DML inside your for-loop, so you're going to hit [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm) if the input list contains more than 100 records.

Let's read your code: for each Lead in `records` you're retrieving itselft (query by id) and updating its own name. Since you already have both the Id and the new value for Name in `records`, you don't need the SOQL, you can simply update it.

```
@AuraEnabled()
public static void saveOutreachProperty(List<Lead> records) {
    if(records != null) {
        update records;
    }
}
```

Comment: thx you for your answer, I edited my code but still It is still not saving .. any idea ?
is it possible that is because I am using Name: 'Abc' and name is not editable for Lead only LastName, FirstName ? How can I map my parameters ?

Comment: @Ben2pop Indeed. Name is not editable, you must set FirstName and LastName accordingly. Could you please provide the output of `console.log(toSaveList)`? Are those fields setted?